# I've hit the DB performance bottleneck, where now?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, caching, database-performance

I have some queries that are taking too long (300ms) now that the DB has grown to a few million records. Luckily for me the queries don't need to look at the majority of this data, that latest 100,000 records will be sufficient so my plan is to maintain a separate table with the most recent 100,000 records and run the queries against this. If anyone has any suggestions for a better way of doing this that would be great. My real question is what are the options if the queries did need to run against the historic data, what is the next step? Things I've thought of:

- Upgrade hardware
- Use an in memory database
- Cache the objects manually in your own data structure

Are these things correct and are there any other options? Do some DB providers have more functionality than others to deal with these problems, e.g. specifying a particular table/index to be entirely in memory?

Sorry, I should've mentioned this, I'm using mysql.

I forgot to mention indexing in the above. Indexing have been my only source of improvement thus far to be quite honest. In order to identify bottlenecks I've been using maatkit for the queries to show whether or not indexes are being utilised.

I understand I'm now getting away from what the question was intended for so maybe I should make another one. My problem is that `EXPLAIN` is saying the query takes 10ms rather than 300ms which jprofiler is reporting. If anyone has any suggestions I'd really appreciate it. The query is:

```
select bv.* 
from BerthVisit bv 
inner join BerthVisitChainLinks on bv.berthVisitID = BerthVisitChainLinks.berthVisitID 
inner join BerthVisitChain on BerthVisitChainLinks.berthVisitChainID = BerthVisitChain.berthVisitChainID 
inner join BerthJourneyChains on BerthVisitChain.berthVisitChainID = BerthJourneyChains.berthVisitChainID 
inner join BerthJourney on BerthJourneyChains.berthJourneyID = BerthJourney.berthJourneyID 
inner join TDObjectBerthJourneyMap on BerthJourney.berthJourneyID = TDObjectBerthJourneyMap.berthJourneyID 
inner join TDObject on TDObjectBerthJourneyMap.tdObjectID = TDObject.tdObjectID 
where 
BerthJourney.journeyType='A' and 
bv.berthID=251860 and 
TDObject.headcode='2L32' and 
bv.depTime is null and 
bv.arrTime > '2011-07-28 16:00:00'
```

and the output from `EXPLAIN` is:

```
+----+-------------+-------------------------+-------------+---------------------------------------------+-------------------------+---------+------------------------------------------------+------+-------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table                   | type        | possible_keys                               | key                     | key_len | ref                                            | rows | Extra                                                 |
+----+-------------+-------------------------+-------------+---------------------------------------------+-------------------------+---------+------------------------------------------------+------+-------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | bv                      | index_merge | PRIMARY,idx_berthID,idx_arrTime,idx_depTime | idx_berthID,idx_depTime | 9,9     | NULL                                           |  117 | Using intersect(idx_berthID,idx_depTime); Using where | 
|  1 | SIMPLE      | BerthVisitChainLinks    | ref         | idx_berthVisitChainID,idx_berthVisitID      | idx_berthVisitID        | 8       | Network.bv.berthVisitID                        |    1 | Using where                                           | 
|  1 | SIMPLE      | BerthVisitChain         | eq_ref      | PRIMARY                                     | PRIMARY                 | 8       | Network.BerthVisitChainLinks.berthVisitChainID |    1 | Using where; Using index                              | 
|  1 | SIMPLE      | BerthJourneyChains      | ref         | idx_berthJourneyID,idx_berthVisitChainID    | idx_berthVisitChainID   | 8       | Network.BerthVisitChain.berthVisitChainID      |    1 | Using where                                           | 
|  1 | SIMPLE      | BerthJourney            | eq_ref      | PRIMARY,idx_journeyType                     | PRIMARY                 | 8       | Network.BerthJourneyChains.berthJourneyID      |    1 | Using where                                           | 
|  1 | SIMPLE      | TDObjectBerthJourneyMap | ref         | idx_tdObjectID,idx_berthJourneyID           | idx_berthJourneyID      | 8       | Network.BerthJourney.berthJourneyID            |    1 | Using where                                           | 
|  1 | SIMPLE      | TDObject                | eq_ref      | PRIMARY,idx_headcode                        | PRIMARY                 | 8       | Network.TDObjectBerthJourneyMap.tdObjectID     |    1 | Using where                                           | 
+----+-------------+-------------------------+-------------+---------------------------------------------+-------------------------+---------+------------------------------------------------+------+---------------------------------------

7 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: Where does EXPLAIN PLAN say the bottleneck is for your troublesome queries?

Comment: "so my plan is to maintain a separate table with the most recent 100,000 records and run the queries against this" - sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: check what your hardware should be able to deliver; check you have the appropriate indexes.

Comment: There's still lots of things you can do. You didn't mention indexing or query optimization (along what @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen was mentioning). What have you done to profile and identify bottlenecks? Also, what database are you using?

Comment: Is jprofiler including the time it takes to send the request to the server and receive back all the results?  Those aren't generally accounted for when looking at the duration of a query inside the database server.  If so then you may need to trim your result set to just what's needed for display.

Comment: @Amir I haven't forgotten. I have quite a lot of suggestions and need to work through various options. It's also quite difficult to have an 'answer' to this question

Comment: Great. Take your time then. Please share it when you find it because I care.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering a design change like this is not a good sign - I bet you still have plenty of performance to squeeze out using EXPLAIN, adjusting db variables and improving the indexes and queries. But you're probably past the point where "trying stuff" works very well. It's an opportunity to learn how to interpret the analyses and logs, and use what you learn for specific improvements to indexes and queries.

If your suggestion were a good one, you should be able to tell us why already. And note that this is a popular pessimization--

[What is the most ridiculous pessimization you've seen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312003/what-is-the-most-ridiculous-pessimization-youve-seen/312041#312041)

Answer (score 3):

1. Make sure all your indexes are optimized. Use `explain` on the query to see if it is using your indexes efficiently.
2. If you are doing some heavy joins then start thinking about doing this calculation in java.
3. Think of using other DBs such NoSQL. You maybe able to do some preprocessing and put data in Memcache to help you a little.

Comment: Agreed. Indexing is not mentionned and offers huge preformance gains on big tables: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108/how-does-database-indexing-work

Comment: Changing the DB is not really an option for everyone.

Comment: I wasn't saying change the DB. I was saying use another db to temporary cache data.

Comment: Denormalization may also be an option.

Comment: @Frank, agreed. Using denorm in the db or some other layer might be good if there is a lot joining.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you have optimised the database and queries, I'd say that rather than chop up the data, the next step is to look at:

a) the mysql configuration and make sure that it is making the most of the hardware

b) look at the hardware. You don't say what hardware you are using. You may find that replication is an option in your case if you can buy a two or three servers to divide up the reads from the database (writes have to be done to a central server, but reads can be read from any number of slaves).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating a separate table for latest results, think about table partitioning. MySQL has this feature built in since version 5.1

---

Just to make it clear: I am not saying this is THE solution for your issues. Just one thing you can try

Answer (score 0):

I would start by trying to optimize the tables/indexes/queries before before taking any of the measures you listed.  Have you dug into the poorly performing queries to the point where you are absolutely convinced you have reached the limit of your RDBMS's capabilities?

Edit: if you are indeed properly optimized, but still have problems, consider creating a Materialized View for the exact data you need.  That may or may not be a good idea based on more factors than you have provided, but I would put it at the top of the list of things to consider.

Answer (score 0):

Searching in the last 100,000 records should be terribly fast, you definitely have problems with the indexes. Use EXPLAIN and fix it.

Comment: Just to be clear, the queries taking 300ms are against approx 9 million at the moment. My idea was to cut the 9 million down to 100,000 to make it quicker

Comment: size doesn't matter as long as you have the right indexes there. if you search only in the last 100,000 it doesn't really matter that there are 8,900,000 other records there. If still in doubt, please post your query and DB schema.

Answer (score 0):

*I understand I'm now getting away from what the question was intended for 
    so maybe I should make another one. My problem is that EXPLAIN is saying 
    the query takes 10ms rather than 300ms which jprofiler is reporting.*

Then your problem (and solution) must be in java, right?