# Is there any way to return IDs of objects inserted with TVP?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, table-valued-parameters

I am doing an insert using tvp of large amount of products. After insert I need IDs of these products. Is there any safe way to get them straight away after stored procedure insert?

Comment: You can do by joining your TVP and original table with unique column and return the column(s) you required by using SELECT statement.

Comment: In the other tvp insert where I know its safe I am just selecting newest objects. But in this case it is possible to do couple of inserts into db at once. I was thinking about technique from second answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8022682/how-can-i-use-a-table-valued-parameter-to-insert-multiple-rows-and-then-return-t
but I am not sure if its safe

Comment: @kali Do you have any unique column for each product other than ID?

Comment: @SelvaTS no, ID is the only one.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you want to return inserted IDs. You can use [`OUTPUT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) clause and magic table `inserted` to return what you need.

```
CREATE TYPE product_type AS TABLE(name VARCHAR(100), barcode INT);

CREATE TABLE products(ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
                      name VARCHAR(100), barcode INT);

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.my_insert_product
   @products product_type READONLY
AS
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO products(name, barcode)
   OUTPUT inserted.ID, inserted.name   -- add columns you need
   SELECT name, barcode
   FROM @products;
END;
```

Calling:

```
DECLARE @t AS product_type;

INSERT INTO @t
VALUES ('Product1', 1), ('Product2', 2), ('Product3', 2),
       ('Product4', 3), ('Product5', 4), ('Product6', 5);

EXEC dbo.my_insert_product @t;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6dd63/1/0)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

With `MERGE` you can output values from the TVP which (without any good reason) is not possible with `INSERT`. You could add a unique key to the TVP that allows your app to understand what rows received what ID.