# Is there a performance issue using a temporary variable?

Tags: java, performance

I have a question about creating new object in java.

Lets say i have methos called: `foo(String[] a)`

I want to pass to `foo` a new `String[]` thats is only for one use what is better for

performance 1 or 2

1.

```
String[] a = new String[]{"a"};

foo(a);
```

2.

```
foo(new String[]{"a"});
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: Is `foo` going to modify `a` in any way?

Comment: Its 1 line of code extra nothing in terms of `performance`.

Comment: a is only for temp use. a wont be used again in the program.

Comment: There is *no* [applicable] performance difference. In both cases exactly *one*  array object is created. Although the first example is invalid as it stands; I presume `new String[]{a}` should be `new String[]{"SomeString"}` or similar.

Comment: @Junaid Well, `doSomethingReallySlow()` is only "a line" :D

Comment: @user2246674 - Yeah. But with respect to the question there is `nothingAffectingPerformance()` :D

Comment: Check the generated bytecode using `javap -c Class.class` that contains the call of `foo` with both approaches, measure them using your fav profiler, do a heavy stress testing on this, just to note that **there is no performance gain or lose with any of those**.

Comment: Most of the time code readability is much more important than slight gains in performance. This looks like a classic example of [premature optimization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization).

Comment: @Junaid what if one line isn't making a `String[]`, but rather an `EightMegabyteAudioFile[]`?

Comment: @gobernador - `WrongInterpretationException` :). I commented on the basis of the question. :)

Comment: @Junaid You're right. *In this case,* instantiating a few strings is trivial. However, I think it's worth noting that under other circumstances, with other object types, this could be a hefty operation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can check the bytecode:

1.

```
  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: iconst_0      
       1: anewarray     #2                  // class java/lang/String
       4: astore_1      
       5: aload_1       
       6: invokestatic  #3                  // Method foo:([Ljava/lang/String;)V
       9: return
```

2.

```
  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: iconst_0      
       1: anewarray     #2                  // class java/lang/String
       4: invokestatic  #3                  // Method foo:([Ljava/lang/String;)V
       7: return
```

The only difference is that in (2), no references are stored (`astore_1`) and none need to be loaded (`aload_1`). This will almost certainly not cause a performance difference (and you shouldn't worry about such minuscule optimizations anyway), but you might as well use option (2) if you're not going to reference `a` again in the program (as you mentioned in [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17711631/is-there-a-performance-issue-using-a-temporary-variable/17711707#comment25813684_17711631)) *and* there is no readability infringement.

I think the readability component is quite important: I would much rather create a variable to store the array (even if I'll never reference this variable more than once) than have one super-long, unreadable line. Of course, in your example, there is no issue with readability, but it's something to consider when more complicated situations arise.

Comment: Looking at the bytecodes doesn't give you a meaningful answer.  The actual performance depends on how the JIT compiler turns those bytecodes into native code.  Different bytecodes do not imply different native code.  (Identical bytecodes do not imply identical native code either ...)

Comment: @StephenC In this particular case, I believe looking at the bytecodes reveals that the first variant can never be JITed into something that outperforms the second variant, while the second variant *can potentially* outperform the first. Obviously, the performance difference here will likely be negligible, as I detail in the answer.

Comment: That is a plausible theory (and probably correct in this case), but it is not factually based.  The JIT is a black box.  It is not specified what or how it optimizes.  If you want to know what *really* happens you need to examine the JIT compiler source code or the native code, not the input bytecodes.

Answer (score 3):

Having temporary local variables *can* help performance if you use them to store frequently used, costly-to-calculate values. For one-shot values, they still can be a big help for *naming* a value and making clear its intent - and the performance cost of this will be absolutely negligible.

Having or not having a variable for storing a one-shot-value is irrelevant in terms of performance, concentrate your efforts in the parts of the code highlighted as bottlenecks by a profiler, and don't waste your time in such irrelevant micro-optimizations. And it's more important to write code that's easy to understand, remember ... "premature optimization is the root of all evil."

Comment: +1 cause I agree. Better add some delay/wait calls, and remove them later, that generates more performance improvements than you'll ever need http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312003/what-is-the-most-ridiculous-pessimization-youve-seen/3187120#3187120

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's possible to answer the question definitively in a general way. Even arshajii's response showing the IL is bounded.

In your code the JIT compiler will optimize this away anyway.

The level of optimization will depend heavily on things like version, platform, implementation, and a million other variables.

... now, if you had a read fence between the two, so the jitter couldn't optimize them away, then you would have a different story.

Comment: I'm interested, do you have a reference that says the JIT will optimise this?

Comment: @selig - AFAIK, no such reference exists ... apart from the JIT compiler source code itself.  However, it is reasonable to assume that the JIT compiler will perform *obvious, simple* optimizations ... like this.  (You can also confirm this by dumping and examining the native code ...)

Comment: @selig - I would ask the other question. This optimization is so basic, I would need documentation to show it's not being made. :-)